# Adding a hint in my python Hangman game

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to IDLE Python,
My IDLE python Hangman game is a bit complex(contains different pictures and windows)
I want to add a one time use hint button in my hangman game.
The word is chosen from a txt file.
How do i get the random choice function to get working?
Here is the start game code :

```
def startgame():

    global word 
    infile_name = getInfile()

    # Choose a word at random from the acquired word list
    word, word_len = chooseWord(infile_name)

    if word_len < 1:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please enter a word!")
        startgame()

    ## lots of variables for actual game ##
    global wordarray 
    wordarray = []
    global guessedletters 
    guessedletters = []

    i = 0
    while i < word_len:
        wordarray.append('_')
        wordarray.append(' ')
        i = i + 1

    global correctcounter 
    correctcounter = 0
    global incorrectcounter 
    incorrectcounter = 0
    ## end variables ##


    game = Toplevel()
    game.wm_title("Hangman")
    game.minsize(100,100)
    game.geometry("500x450")

    man = PhotoImage(file="gallows.gif")
    hiddenword = StringVar()
    gamelabel1 = Label(game, image=man)
    gamelabel1.image = man
    gamelabel1.pack()

    gamelabel2 = Label(game, textvariable=hiddenword)
    gamelabel2.pack()

    guessfield = Entry(game)
    guessfield.pack()

    remainingguesses = 9 - incorrectcounter
    wordprint = ''.join(wordarray) + "\n"
    wordprint = wordprint + "Guessed Letters: " + ', '.join(guessedletters) + "\n"
    wordprint = wordprint + "Incorrect Guesses Remaining: " + str(remainingguesses) + "\n"
    hiddenword.set(wordprint)

    bguessletter = Button(game, text="Guess Letter", width=15, command=lambda:
        letterguess(guessfield, hiddenword, game, gamelabel1, man))
    bguessletter.pack()

    bguessword = Button(game, text="Guess Word [ONE CHANCE]", width=25, command=lambda:wordguess(guessfield, hiddenword, game, man))
    bguessword.pack()

    game.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is the chooseWord  implementation?

Comment: Include needed imports in posted code.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and reduce code to minimum needed for question.

Answer (score 0):

You want random choice? Then that seems like you want `random.choice`. See [random choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Comment: Ok. Will check. Thank you